# Chinese letters showing up when replying to email in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I received an email today that was sent out to our organisation. When I clicked reply in Outlook the following characters appeared on top of the other characters:

> 䐼噉氠湡㵧癳挠慬獳伽瑵潬歯敍獳条䡥慥敤⁲污杩㵮氢晥≴䐠剉∽呌≒‾䘼乏⁔慆散∽≃匠穩㵥㸲㰭剂‾䈼䘾⼼㹂䘠†䈼㹒㰠㹂㱓䈯‾㱤剂‾䈼吾⼼㹂嘠䈼㹒†䈼[CHAR](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/50238/UTF-8-character)⼼㹂䨠䈼㹒†㰠䘯乏㹔㰠䐯噉㰾䥄㹖⼼䥄㹖

I had to edit one character away from the original message because I got the error from superuser:

> Body cannot contain "[CHAR](http://www.utf8icons.com/character/50238/UTF-8-character)". Unlucky.

These letters were not visible before I hit reply and it was the same for my colleagues who received it. The email is written in plain text so I can't even select "View Source" either. Has anyone experienced this before?

Opened message, note Plain Text:
[image]

Replying:
[image]

Comment: `Plain text` should not be related to `view source` . . .

Comment: @Law29: It is – Outlook (with its X.400ish heritage) has two separate options for viewing the message's MIME headers (under "Properties") and for viewing the raw body of a HTML message (under "View Source").

Comment: @Law29 I can `view source` in every `HTML`-email but not in any `Plain Text`-email so I actually think it is related.

Comment: OK, your `view source` means viewing the HTML part as text, not the actual mail source. @grawity has it right and has even decoded the beginning of the message (which seems to be HTML, actually). If this was spam, I wouldn't worry about it...

Comment: A year later and this bug still appears to be present? Cross reference with https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_win10/outlook-2016-chinese-characters-appearing-in/35d2d052-e1c3-4ba3-9563-ee471efce2e6 and still no fix as of August this year

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, Outlook is [misinterpreting](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040324-00/?p=40093) the message body as UTF-16-LE while it is in fact regular ASCII-based text. (The given sample is purely ASCII, the whole message might be UTF-8.)

```
misdecoded:    䐼     噉     氠     湡     㵧
 (Unicode):  U+443C U+5649 U+6C20 U+6E61 U+3D67
 raw bytes:  3C 44  49 56  20 6c  61 6e  67 3d
     UTF-8:  <   D  I   V  ␣   l  a   n  g   =
```

The given sample decodes as:

```
<DIV lang=sv class=OutlookMessageHeader align="left" DIR="LTR"> <FONT Face="C" Size=2>-<BR> <B>F</B> F  <BR> <B>S</B> d<BR> <B>T</B> V<BR>  <BCHAR</B> J<BR>   </FONT> </DIV><DIV></DIV>
```

I don't know why Outlook uses the wrong encoding. The sender might have specified it wrongly in the *Content-Type* header (see message's "Properties" window); it could be that the message was prepared by an auto-mailer which confused UTF-8 and UTF-16. If Outlook and/or MS Exchange are involved, it becomes twice as difficult to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Based on grawity's answer I checked the header settings. This solution worked for me:

> 1. Go to **File -> Advanced** and look up the **International Options** header.
> 2. Uncheck "Use English for message headers on replies and forwards and for forward notifications."
> 3. Restart Outlook
> 4. Test reply

I work on windows 10, Outlook Version 1902 (Office 365).

Your experience may differ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iconv` command to convert these chinese characters back to text:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16LE input.txt
```

There is an online `iconv` you can use to fix the text [here](http://iconv.onlinephpfunctions.com/).
Just use UTF-8 as the input and UTF-16LE as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Change the encoding setting in MS outlook from UTF 8 to western European.

Go to File -> Options - Advanced and look up the International Options header.
Preferred Encoding for outgoing messages: **Western European (ISO)**

Preferred Encoding for outgoing vCards: **Western European (Windows)**

then restart outlook and check. your issue will be fixed..